# htaccess variable rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, variables, url-rewriting

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^archive/article/([0-9]+)/?$ archive/article.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

The url: http://mywebsite.com/archive/article/2/ gives a 404 error.
The page is still accessible via the old url: http://mywebsite.com/archive/article.php?id=2

It looks like the rewriterule isn't working.

Maybe it needs a REQUISTED URI before the rule, but I don't really know how to.

Comment: Is it a spelling mistake here?? `archieve/article.php?id=$1 [NC,L]`

Comment: No, that's dutch for archive, but I forgot to translate that word in the code above. But thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: But then I didn't understand your problem? You are entering `http://mywebsite.com/archive/article/2/` in your browser right? Are you getting 404?

Comment: Indeed, but it should not @anubhava

Comment: 1st basic question: Is this .htaccess enabled? Q2: Do you have other rules in it (if yes then post it). Q3. Do you have any other .htaccess also?

Comment: What do you mean with enabled? And no, this is the only thing whats in my htaccess file. No, this is the only htaccess file on my website, it's located in the root. @anubhava

Comment: Hmmm let's first make sure .htaccess is being read. Try putting same garbage text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: Yes, a error appears @anubhava

Comment: Hmm I tried same rule and it worked for me so it is some local env issue on your end. What is location of this .htaccess?

Comment: In the root of the website @anubhava. It works now! aparrantly my server is a bit slow. But now the css and images aren't loading, it's just a page full of text, or is that also a matter of time

Comment: ok can you insert this rule: `RewriteRule ^foo$ /bar [L,R]` and then visit `/foo` to see if changes to `/bar` or not.

Comment: Yes, it does change into /bar @anubhava

Comment: Hmm ok, can you add this line on top: `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews` and then try your archive URI

Comment: `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^archief/artikel/([0-9]+)/?$ archief/artikel.php?id=$1 [NC,L]` This script doesn't work, if this was what you wanted me to test.

Comment: Keep your rewrite rule as: `RewriteRule ^archief/artikel/([0-9]+)/?$ /archief/artikel.php?id=$1 [NC,L]` and then try `http://mywebsite.com/archief/artikel/2/`

Comment: I did, but nothing @anubhava. I have also tried the slash in front of the `archief/` but no result. My htaccess looks like this at the moment: `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^archief/artikel/([0-9]+)/?$ /archief/artikel.php?id=$1 [NC,L]`

Comment: I can't think of any reason why it won't work. You rule worked on my local setup. i still suspect some local config/setup issue on your end but it is difficult to guess for me.